# std::cin not functioning within do-while loop

Tags: c++, visual-studio, c++11

I am trying to create a simple program that reads in range limits and then creates a random number between those ranges. Everything is functioning in my program, but when I run the code, the first message prints to the user, then I go to type in my max range, push enter, and the cursor just moves to the next line, still asking for input.

I don't see what is causing this in my code, and I am stumped.

Here is my code so far:

```
#include<iostream>
#include<limits>

using std::cout;
using std::cin;
using std::endl;

int main(){

    int maxRange; //to store the maximum range of our random numbers

    do {
       cout << "Please enter a maximum range \n";
       //use clear funtion to clear the fail bit
       cin.clear();
       //use ignore function to avoid bad input
       cin.ignore(std::numeric_limits<std::streamsize>::max(), '\n');
    } while(!(cin >> maxRange)); //continue loop if cin fails

    int minRange; //to store the minimum range of random numbers

    do {
       cout << "Please enter a minimum range \n";
       //use clear funtion to clear the fail bit
       cin.clear();
       //use ignore function to avoid bad input
       cin.ignore(std::numeric_limits<std::streamsize>::max(), '\n');
    } while(!(cin >> minRange)); //continue loop if cin fails

    int randomNumber = rand() % maxRange + minRange;

    cout << "The random number that you have generated is: " << randomNumber << endl;

    return 0;
}
```

EDIT:
The issue was the ignore function. Here is my working code for the corrected loop:

```
if(!(cin)){
    cin.clear();
    cin.ignore(std::numeric_limits<std::streamsize>::max(), '\n');
   }
```

Comment: Have you tried running in a debugger? Hint: what happens first, reading the number, or skipping a line?

Comment: Yes I have run it through a debugger many times. It will print my request for input, then once I enter input and push enter, it just continues to wait for input. It isn't the clear() function, I have commented it out completely and rebuilt my project, and the problem still shows up.

Comment: You might want to test your "corrected" code a bit more thoroughly (with bad inputs as well as good inputs). I doubt it does what you want it to do in all cases.

Comment: Wow thanks Ben. Rough day for me I guess. I fixed it now (I think).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `cin.ignore()` in your first `do..while()` loop discards your first line of input before trying to read a value in the loop condition.  Your program does (kind of) work if you enter the maximum range twice, since it successfully reads the second line.  Maybe remove the `cin.ignore()` line in the first loop.

You also have an error later on in selecting the random number, though...

```
int randomNumber = rand() % maxRange + minRange;
```

should be maybe:

```
int randomNumber = rand() % (1 + maxRange - minRange) + minRange;
```

to get a range of `minRange` to `maxRange` inclusive.

Comment: Thanks! You were right about the ignore function. I wrapped it in an if statement. Also, I took that code for random number generation directly form the API, here: http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cstdlib/rand/?kw=rand and it is working as is.

Comment: The value after the `%` operator is giving the *size* of the range, not the end of it.

Comment: Wow, good eye. You are indeed correct sir. I re-ran my code a couple times and it was way off.